# Measuring multiple samples from a specific point vs multiple samples each from a random point

Tags: sampling, sample-size, cluster-sample

I have been reading about sampling and I am wondering about the following: If your interested in measuring the rate of change of your population, ideally I assume you would choose a point at random in the series and then measure the rate of change x minutes later (where x is a randomly generated number between your minimum and maximum value of the period of interest). The aforementioned process would then be repeated a certain number of time to reach the required number of samples.

Is it possible to reduce the number of randomly selected start points and instead measure the rate of change, from that start point, over multiple x minute periods? For example, measuring the rate of change experienced after 2,10,17 minutes (all randomly generated) from a single start point before selecting a new start point and calculating the rate of change for 3 more random time durations.

I expect the number of start points would still have to be relatively high to avoid any issues due to the fact that each group of 3 rates would be correlated?

Are there any rules of thumb regarding the total number of samples vs how many could be calculated from each start point?

Walter

Comment: Please provide more context and details. This question is too broad to be answerable. Good answers could be as simple as "use two samples, one at the beginning and one at the end," depending on the nature of the measurements, the population, the costs of sampling, the investigation objectives, and more. The references to taking random times and durations are particularly puzzling, so it would help if you could explain why that might be important.

Comment: Good evening @whuber, I was thinking of cases where you are trying to process a large number of data points, thus the sampling cost would be high. Investigation objectives I assume would be to see if there is a correlation between the length of time and the rate of change. Regarding the random times, I thought that would help reduce the correlation between each group of 3 rates. I am new to this though so its quite possible that I'm mistaken.

Comment: I'm afraid your description is too abstract for me to be confident I understand what you're doing. If you could be more concrete--such as displaying a simple example of your data--that might help readers see what the issues really are. You also seem to be focusing on your proposed solution. That usually doesn't work: it's better to explain the *problem* so that people don't get locked into addressing a solution that might be inappropriate or inferior to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly. As mentioned at the start of the question, I have just finished reading about sampling and i was wondering how it would be possible to reduce the time taken to take x samples. 1 possible way I thought about was to take multiple measurements from a specific start point, rather than selecting multiple start points.

Comment: You are working from some kind of conceptual context which you have yet to reveal: evidently you have in mind some particular *way* of sampling some particular *something* that varies in some undescribed way over time. Until you disclose these specifics, it will be difficult to guess what you are writing about and even harder to formulate a good answer.

Comment: I was cycling with one of my friends and he works for a company producing weather reports for oil companies / measuring wave heights, predicting 100 yr storms etc. He had mentioned that they have to process large amounts of data. So i was just wondering what the implications were if you took multiple samples at a several points vs single samples at multiple points. I assume that as long as the number of sample points is still large, there would not be much of an issue. Sorry for not providing this info upfront, but its more just a random thought i had after reading the sampling chapter.

Comment: It looks like a legitimate question about *time series sampling.* Where it goes awry is that you imply the purpose is to "measure rate of change" of a "population." In the applications you mention, the purpose typically is to *forecast* a *process.* Briefly, it sounds like your question is "is there an optimal way to sample a time series, when the sampling budget is limited, for the purpose of (estimating the parameters of the process)/(forecasting future values)/(some other purpose)?" Am I getting close to a correct understanding?

Comment: There is rarely such a thing as "THE" rate of change for a time series. If you now move on to reading about time series, there will be discussions of decomposition of a time series into a trend, "seasonality" (over the year for precipitation; over the day for the temperature; over the week for financial markets that don't trade on the weekend; etc.), correlated pink noise, and pure random noise. Depending on how you specify such a decomposition, you might get rather different answers.